# Composting pineapple crowns, corn sheath and kernel

Tags: compost, pineapple

Do these take a long time to compost, if so is there some way to speed up the process. Or should I leave them out of the compost bin altogether?

Answer (score 1):

The crown leaves likely contain a semi-valuable fibre; there is a variety of pineapple specifically grown for those fibres. They are very fine and durable, so the leaves will, yes, take a while to break down. Pulling the crown apart into its separate leaves would help to break them down more quickly. You could consider using the crown to propagate more plants rather than compost it.

As for sheath and kernel, I presume by these terms you mean the inedible core and the outer skin? These would appear to be a prime candidate for worm- or vermi-composting. If you can chop up the core somewhat and put the outer shell, intact as a cylinder packed with core bits, into the vermi-compost bin this is the kind of environment that worms will congregate in and take care of the breakdown for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "semi-valuable fibre"?

Answer (score 1):

I find they take a long time to break down in my compost bin. The more surface area a substance has the more area there is for it to be broken down by microbes and other small creatures. To create that surface area the best thing is to chop it up as much as you can.